# Proof of If $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ with $A$ inductive set then $\Bbb{N}\subseteq A$

Tags: real-numbers

In calculus class, I saw a proof of this, but I am not convinced.

Note:
A$\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is inductive if and only if 1$\in A$ and $\forall x \in A \Rightarrow x+1 \in A$.

I tried to do a proof here:

Suppose that $A$ is a inductive set.

By definition, $\Bbb{N}$ is the untersection of all inductive sets.

That is:
$$\Bbb{N} = \bigcap A_i\in I$$
where $A_i$  is a inductive set.

This is the same as:
$$\Bbb{N} = \{x: x\in A_1 \land x\in A_2 \land ... \land x\in A \land ... \}$$

Thus, $x \in \Bbb{N} \Rightarrow$ x $\in A$.

By definition of a subset, $\Bbb{N} \subseteq A$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, this proof is correct.